# Can a bluetooth device send messages to WiFi?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, routes, wireless

I'd like to send a message from bluetooth to Wifi, is that possible? I have a long gap I need to cover, and WiFi is more suitable for distant transmission. I want to send a message from a bluetooth device to wifi, which will then send the message back to a bluetooth device.

Comment: The simple answer would be that you cannot. Bluetooth and WiFi are two different technologies for wireless data transfer that are incompatible with each other. It is however not impossible to use bluetooth to access the internet. Good example is the tethering possibility of the iphone or your windows pc. Speeds and distance to the hotspot are limiting factors, you're much better off using WiFi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, Bluetooth and WiFi are different standards that cannot be interoperated.**

To establish Bluetooth connections in Android you should use the `Bluetooth` classes. You can read more about them [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html).

Android also supports peer-to-peer WiFi connections, a getting started guide on which you can read [here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html).

Comment: I know how to use bluetooth, but wasn't sure if there was some way to make that work easily. I suppose i'll have to make the converter myself. Just didn't want to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for the post, and your time.